# ¿Cómo comprobar si un grupo de alumnos está lleno?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa de **10 alumnos distribuidos en 2 grupos** (dos arreglos) con longitud distinta (uno tiene 3 espacios y el otro 7) y que la asignación de grupo de cada alumno sea aleatorio entre `grupo1` y `grupo2`.

Mi problema es que cuando un grupo está lleno, el programa no redirecciona al alumno a un grupo que tenga espacio, sino que marca un error.

Mi consulta es, de que manera puedo hacer para que el programa diga **"Oh, el alumno Juan tiene que ir al grupo 1 pero ya esta lleno, bueno, lo mandamos a un grupo que tenga espacio para él"**

Este es mi código:

```
package Practico2;
import java.util.*;

public class Ejercicio10 {
    static int n=10;
    static int a=3;
    static int b=7;

    static String nombre;
    static int num=0;

static String lista[]=new String[n];
static String grupo1[]=new String[a];   
static String grupo2[]=new String[b];   
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

static int cont=0;
static int cont2=0;

    static void asignado() { // Numero del grupo que va a ir la persona //
        num = (int) (Math.random()*2)+1;
    }
    
    static void grupo1(String grupox[]) {
        if (num==1) {
            if((grupox[cont]==null)){
                    grupox[cont]=sc.next();
                    cont++;
                    num=0;
                } else {
                    num = 2;
                }
            }
        }
    
    static void grupo2(String grupox[]) {
        if (num==2) {
            if((grupox[cont2]==null)) {
                grupox[cont2]=sc.next();
                cont2++;
                num=0;
            } else {
                num = (int) (Math.random()*2)+1;
            }
        }       
}
    
    static  void mostrar(String vectx [],int x) { /* Mostrar el grupo elegido por el usuario */
        for (int i=0;i<x;i++){
                System.out.print(vectx[i]+"- ");}
        }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            asignado();
            System.out.println(num);
            do {
                switch (num) {
                case 1:
                    grupo1(grupo1);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    grupo2(grupo2);
                    break;
                }
            } while (num!=0);
            
        }
        
        System.out.println(num);
        System.out.println("Que grupo desea observar? 1-2");
        num=sc.nextInt();
        switch (num) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Grupo 1:");
            mostrar(grupo1,cont);
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Grupo 2:");
            mostrar(grupo2,cont2);
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: No sé si es lo que buscas, pero el tamaño de un array/arreglo es la propiedad `length` (por ejemplo, `grupox.length`)

Comment: Tienes demasiadas propiedades y metodos static, para ese caso en especial no repercute en mucho, pero se considera una mala practica ir colocando `static` por todas partes, el fin de `static` es usarlo como ultimo recurso y en los casos en los que necesites solo 1 propiedad u metodo que pueda ser accedido para cualquier clase o en otro contexto estatico, pero los problemas de tener `static` en todas partes es que perjudican a este lenguaje orientado a objetos, si de pronto te interesa puedes ver este enlace: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5VVVV192_oo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edito la respuesta.

Siguiendo tu enunciado, no entiendo el funcionamiento del bucle while. ¿Por qué crees que es necesario?¿Hay algo que no haya entendido?
Además, no te hace falta comprobar dentro de grupo1 y grupo2 el valor de la variable num, ya que la filtras en el switch-case.

Si hay algo mas a parte de tu enunciado, dímelo para tenerlo en cuenta, pero siguiéndolo, te debería valer con lo siguiente:

Debido a que sabes los tamaños de los grupos ( a y b ) y sabes cuantos valores se han insertado en cada grupo ( cont y cont2 ), en el bucle en el que insertas los datos, prueba que no hayas llegado al tamaño de cada uno:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Ejercicio10{
    static int n=10;
    static int a=3;
    static int b=7;

    static String nombre;
    static int num=0;

    static String lista[]=new String[n];
    static String grupo1[]=new String[a];   
    static String grupo2[]=new String[b];   
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

    static int cont=0;
    static int cont2=0;

    static void asignado() { // Numero del grupo que va a ir la persona //
        num = (int) (Math.random()*2)+1;
    }
    
    static void grupo1(String grupox[]) {        
            System.out.println("Inserta un alumno para el grupo 1:");
            grupox[cont]=sc.next();
            cont++;
                    
        }
    
    static void grupo2(String grupox[]) {   
            System.out.println("Inserta un alumno para el grupo 2:");
            grupox[cont2]=sc.next();
            cont2++;               
   }       

    
    static  void mostrar(String vectx [],int x) { /* Mostrar el grupo elegido por el usuario */
        for (int i=0;i<x;i++){
                System.out.print(vectx[i]+"- ");}
        }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            asignado();
            
            switch (num) {
                case 1:
                    if(cont < a) //Si cabe en el grupo 1
                        grupo1(grupo1);
                    else if( cont2 < b ){ // Si cabe el en grupo 2
                        System.out.println("No cabe en el grupo1, se insertará en el 2");
                        grupo2(grupo2);            
                    }
                    else { // si a+b>n, podría ocurrir.
                        System.out.println("No cabe en ningún grupo");
                        num = 0;
                    }
                break;
                case 2:
                    if( cont2 < b ){ // Si cabe el en grupo 2                       
                        grupo2(grupo2);            
                    }
                    else if(cont < a) { //Si cabe en el grupo 1
                        System.out.println("No cabe en el grupo2, se insertará en el 1");
                        grupo1(grupo1);
                    }
                    else { // si a+b>n, podría ocurrir.
                        System.out.println("No cabe en ningún grupo");
                        num = 0;
                    }
                break;
            }
          
            
        }

        System.out.println("Que grupo desea observar? 1-2");
        num=sc.nextInt();
        switch (num) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Grupo 1:");
            mostrar(grupo1,cont);
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Grupo 2:");
            mostrar(grupo2,cont2);
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: No funcionara, el usuario usa numeros random y no el ciclo para asignar los espacios en memoria, si se hace de esta forma casi nunca todos los espacios de ambos arrays seran llenados, y algunos que ya contenian un valor seran reemplazados por otro. Aunque al fin y al cabo no se si la intencion es que se llene un espacio en memoria de manera aleatoria pero siempre y cuidando que ese espacio no haya sido llenado y ademas que el array no este lleno, si ese es el caso se necesita una logica un poco mas compleja.

Comment: Si ese no es el caso el usuario aun tiene un inconveniente peligroso en su codigo, el cual haria que aquello que propones aun no funcione.

Comment: Mi enunciado dice lo siguente:
En un taller de computacion se deben repartir los alumnos en 4 grupos. Se ingresa aleatoriamente un nombre y numero de grupo, los grupos tienen 10,11,12,14 alumnos respectivamente.
Realizar la carga y un menu de opciones que permita consultar el listado de grupo solicitado y ordenado alfabeticamente.
Yo lo hice mas pequeño al listado para facilitar a la hora de probar el programa, pero este es el enunciado tal cual.

Comment: Ya lo pude resolver, muchas gracias!

Comment: A pesar que esta respuesta responde la duda del OP, el código no es reutilizable..

Answer (score 2):

Si el enunciado dice:

> > En un taller de computación se deben repartir los alumnos en 4 grupos. Se ingresa aleatoriamente un nombre y numero de grupo, los grupos tienen 10,11,12,14 alumnos respectivamente.

No necesitas enfocarte en redireccionar el alumno a otro grupo, sino, en comprobar que grupo no puede aceptar más alumnos.

Por ejemplo, puedes almacenar objetos de tipo `Grupo` en un [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) e ir comprobando en cada iteración si el grupo llegó a su límite, si se cumpliera la condición, eliminamos el objeto del *ArrayList* y de este modo, vamos **descartando los grupos que no tengan más cupo**. Con esta lógica, no estaríamos generando de forma aleatoria el número de un grupo, sino, un índice que lo usaremos para identificar el espacio de memoria del *ArrayList*.

Dado una lista (se puede llamar `grupos`) de `N` (en este caso sería `4`) elementos, donde el índice va de `0` a `N-1`, el algoritmo quedaría así:

**1.-** Generamos un índice aleatorio de `0` a `N-1`.

**2.-** Comprobamos si el grupo está lleno, si esto se cumple, eliminamos el grupo de la lista llamada `grupos`, luego debemos disminuir la cantidad de elementos de la lista. Esto último se lo hace porque en la siguiente iteración no generaremos el mismo rango de índices. Por ejemplo, si elimino el grupo `2` de la lista (que estará en la posición `1` del *ArrayList*), en la próxima iteración, no genero de forma aleatorio un índice que esté en el rango de `0` a `3`, sino, de `0` a `2`, de lo contrario, la máquina virtual de Java nos lanzará una excepción por pasarnos de los límites de la *lista*. Con esta lógica conseguimos **solo trabajar con los grupos que aún tengan espacios.**

**3.-** Si no se cumple el paso **2**, podemos asignar el alumno en el grupo.

**4.-** Repetir los pasos 1, 2 y 3 hasta que la lista se quede sin grupos.

Para lograr implementar este algoritmo, debemos aprovechar la programación orientada a objetos que nos proporciona Java, ya que con esto, podemos lograr hacer un código reutilizable (es decir, no tener códigos redundante) sin la necesidad de complicarnos tanto.

La clase `Grupo` está diseñado de esta forma:

```java
class Grupo
{
    private int id; //Identificación del grupo.
    private int tam; //Cantidad máxima de alumnos que puede haber en el grupo.
    private int cont; //Cantidad actual de alumnos que haya en el grupo.
    private String[] alumnos;//El array donde estará almacenado los nombres de cada alumno.
    
    //El constructor por defecto asigna el tamaño máximo del grupo.
    public Grupo(int tam, int id)
    {
        alumnos = new String[tam];
        this.tam = tam;
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    //Obtiene la cantidad actual de alumnos.
    public int getCantidad()
    {
        return cont;
    }
    
    //Obtiene la cantidad máxima de alumnos que puede tener el grupo.
    public int length()
    {
        return tam;
    }
    
    //Obtiene el nombre de un alumno.
    public String getAlumno(int index)
    {
        return alumnos[index];
    }
    
    //Actualiza la cantidad actual de alumnos.
    public void actCantidad()
    {
        cont = cont + 1;
    }
    
    //Asigna el nombre del alumno en X posición del array.
    public void setAlumno(String nombre, int index)
    {
        alumnos[index] = nombre;
        
        //Este código es para saber en que grupo se agregó el alumno.
        System.out.println("Nombre: "+ nombre + " Grupo: "+ id);
    }
}
```

Las propiedades de la clase `Grupo` nos servirán para saber:

- La *identificación* del grupo.
- El tamaño máximo de alumnos que puede tener el grupo.
- La cantidad actual de alumnos que tendrá el grupo.
- La lista de todos los alumnos registrados en el grupo.

Luego por último, añadimos la clase principal:

```java
public class Ejercicio10 
{  
    //Método que se encarga de asignar el alumno en el grupo.
    static void asignarGrupo(Grupo gr, Scanner sc)
    {
        gr.setAlumno(sc.next(), gr.getCantidad());
        gr.actCantidad();
    }
    
    //Muestra los alumnos de X grupo
    static void mostrar(Grupo gr) 
    { 
        for (int i=0; i < gr.getCantidad(); i++)
            System.out.print(gr.getAlumno(i) + "- ");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        //Cantidad máxima de grupos.
        int n = 3;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        int num=0;
        //En esta lista se mantiene los objetos
        List<Grupo> grupos = new ArrayList<>();
        grupos.add(new Grupo(3, 1)); //El primer grupo tiene como espacio hasta 3 alumnos.
        grupos.add(new Grupo(3, 2)); //El segundo grupo tiene como espacio hasta 3 alumnos.
        grupos.add(new Grupo(3, 3));//El tercer grupo tiene como espacio hasta 3 alumnos.
        //Esta lista será una auxiliar, ya que la vamos alterar y no podemos modificar la lista original.
        List<Grupo> aux = new ArrayList<>(grupos);
        do
        {
            //Obtenemos un indice aleatorio para acceder a x posición de la lista
            num = rand.nextInt(n);
            //Si la cantidad actual de X grupo llega a ser igual a la cantidad máxima de alumnos que puede tener el grupo..
            if(aux.get(num).getCantidad() == aux.get(num).length())
            {
                //Eliminamos el grupo de la lista auxiliar, esto quiere decir que este grupo no tiene más cupo.
                aux.remove(num);
                //Decrementamos n, ya que debemos generar indices aleatorios de 0 a N - 1
                --n;
            }
            else //De lo contrario, podemos asignar un alumno en el grupo
                asignarGrupo(aux.get(num), sc);
        }while(aux.size() != 0); //Mientras la lista auxiliar tenga grupos con cupos, el bucle se seguirá ejecutando..
        
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Que grupo desea observar? 1-3");
            num = sc.nextInt();
            //Aquí se debe añadir una validación para que el usuario solo pueda ingresar grupos de 1 a 3, de lo contrario, la jvm lanzará una excepción..
            System.out.println("Grupo " + num +":");
            mostrar(grupos.get(num - 1));
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Como verás, lo que realmente resuelve el problema es esta parte:

```java
List<Grupo> grupos = new ArrayList<>();
grupos.add(new Grupo(3, 1)); //El primer grupo tiene como espacio hasta 3 alumnos.
grupos.add(new Grupo(3, 2)); //El segundo grupo tiene como espacio hasta 3 alumnos.
grupos.add(new Grupo(3, 3));//El tercer grupo tiene como espacio hasta 3 alumnos.
//Esta lista será una auxiliar, ya que la vamos alterar y no podemos modificar la lista original.
List<Grupo> aux = new ArrayList<>(grupos);
do
{
    //Obtenemos un indice aleatorio para acceder a x posición de la lista
    num = rand.nextInt(n);
    //Si la cantidad actual de X grupo llega a ser igual a la cantidad máxima de alumnos que puede tener el grupo..
    if(aux.get(num).getCantidad() == aux.get(num).length())
    {
        //Eliminamos el grupo de la lista auxiliar, esto quiere decir que este grupo no tiene más cupo.
        aux.remove(num);
        //Decrementamos n, ya que debemos generar indices aleatorios de 0 a N - 1
        --n;
    }
    else //De lo contrario, podemos asignar un alumno en el grupo
        asignarGrupo(aux.get(num), sc);
}while(aux.size() != 0); //Mientras la lista auxiliar tenga grupos con cupos, el bucle se seguirá ejecutando..
```

Y listo, con este tipo de implementación logramos rellenar los alumnos en cada grupo de forma aleatoria sin tanto lió y al fin de cuenta, nos sirve para trabajar con muchos grupos.